# 3d plot of data with matplotlib gives wrong result

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have some data and I want to create a 3d plot in matplotlib (python3) from it. I am using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')
chiT0,af = np.meshgrid(chiT[0],F[0])

ax.plot_surface(chiT0,af,c[0])                  
plt.show()
```

where chiT[0], F[0] and c[0] are arrays with data. The plot sould look similar like plateau but it looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how this can be?

Comment: I suspect you are having ordering issues of the data?

Comment: Without having the data and/or errors, there is very little we can do. Can you post more detail?

Comment: Show you data set and full code listing. I guess you data was reordered.

Comment: I agree with @tcaswell it looks like an ordering issue.